# JavaScript Object.assign optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-closure-compiler

I am using the Babel plugin [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) because I prefer the readability of the code.

For example, this:

```
const a = {
  x: 1
};

const b = {
  ...a, 
  y: 1
}
```

... becomes this:

```
const a = {
  x: 1
};

const b = Object.assign({}, a, { x: 1 });
```

Now, `Object.assign` is [quite inefficient](https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign/), but in many cases it can be optimized away.

For example, this:

```
function foo(i) {
  const a = {
    x: 1
  };
  const b = {
    ...a, 
    y: i
  };
  return b;
}
```

... is equivalent to this:

```
function foo(i) {
  return {
    x: 1,
    y: i;
  };
}
```

This is just a simple example, but there are many in my code. *I do not want to change my code because I find it very readable as it is now*. However, I *do* want better performance.

So, is there a tool that can examine JavaScript code that uses `Object.assign` and replace it with object-mutation or object-creation where possible?

---

Note: I had a look at Google Closure compiler, but it did not work for a small `Object.assign` example, even with advanced optimizations.

Comment: Although I'm really interested in this question, isn't this asking for a library/off-site resource?

Comment: Hmm perhaps. If a mod could migrate it to a more appropriate place that would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think `Object.assign` is "quite inefficient"?

Comment: Well, the spread syntax *is* quite inefficient.